# Shared preferences inside broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

In my app,i want to use Shared Preferences inside a broadcast receiver...But i cant access the getPreferences() method inside...

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I cant call with the context object...any other method???

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can use Context from `onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)` of BroadReceiver.

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = arg0.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 
                                                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

Comment: No, it depends on your usage.

Comment: @subrussn90 there is, security issue.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub please ellaborate it more or give better answer!

Comment: @LalitPoptani so let me teach you: android doc: "Creating world-readable files is very dangerous, and likely to cause security holes in applications. It is strongly discouraged; instead, applications should use more formal mechanism for interactions such as ContentProvider, BroadcastReceiver, and Service. There are no guarantees that this access mode will remain on a file, such as when it goes through a backup and restore. "

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub and where is world-readable? used in my answer?

Comment: @LalitPoptani well, because you didnt even read my FIRST message and you just started flaming me... I was talking to subrussn90, NOT you. look above