# How to change content of variable inside a Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my `BroadcastReceiver` I'm trying to detect a missed call.

So I'm checking if the phone goes from `EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` to `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE`. I'm giving each state a fixed value and checking if a particular value is obtained.

However, the values of the variable are not reflected as I expect them to. I've tried using `SharedPreferences`, but I don't think they can be used inside a `BroadcastReceiver`. I've tried calling in a different class' object but it's giving me errors.

How can I achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use some king of persistent storage to keep your state variable value between receiving broadcasts. You can use `mysql`, `files` or better `SharedPreferences`. [You can easily use `SharedPreferences` from `BroadcastReceiver`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075030/shared-preferences-inside-broadcastreceiver).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think of using context variable!