# How to save app settings?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How can I save the the settings of my app? Right now, for example, I have a togglebutton to turn on/off. But if I restart my phone, the toggle button is turned back on. Its not saving the settings if I completely close the app. Can I like the save the settings to the phone as cookies?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use **Shared Preferences**. Like so:

Put this at the top of your class: `public static final String myPref = "preferenceName";`

Create these methods for use, or just use the content inside of the methods whenever you want:

```
public String getPreferenceValue()
{
   SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(myPref,0);
   String str = sp.getString("myStore","TheDefaultValueIfNoValueFoundOfThisKey");
   return str;
}

public void writeToPreference(String thePreference)
{
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(myPref,0).edit();
   editor.putString("myStore", thePreference);
   editor.commit();
}
```

You could call them like this:

```
writeToPreference("on"); // stores that the preference is "on"
writeToPreference("off"); // stores that the preference is "off"

if (getPreferenceValue().equals("on"))
{
   // turn the toggle button on
}
else if (getPreferenceValue().equals("off"))
{
   // turn the toggle button off
}
else if (getPreferenceValue().equals("TheDefaultValueIfNoValueFoundOfThisKey"))
{
   // a preference has not been created
}
```

**Note:** you can do this with `boolean`, `integer`, etc.

All you have to do is change the `String` storing and reading to `boolean`, or whatever type you want.

Here is a link to a pastie with the code above modified to store a `boolean` instead: http://pastie.org/8400737

Comment: Thanks! this is very helpful. I put the calling sharedPereferences in  a method. Is there a way to try and retrieving sharedPreferences from another class? Like I want to access the shared pereferences from a broadCastReceiver

Comment: The `shared preferences`, with the way I've written it, can be accessed in any class. Make sure to just keep the `"preferenceName"` which is `myPref` the same in both classes; and keep the `"myStore"` the same as well.

Comment: can you tell me what the myPref is? What isi t used for?

Comment: If I were to access this in another class, do I need to create a SharedPreferences object there as well?

Comment: I also did this: SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 

How does that differ from yours?

Comment: You can copy and paste the methods into another class, and call them the exact same way in both. So yes, you need to create the object again, if that's what you mean. `myPref` is just a `String`. You could delete `myPref` and just replace it with `"preferenceName"` in the methods. The `String` just determines which **Preference** you've created is accessed.

Comment: `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` could possibly limit your accessibility to the **Shared Preferences**. To be honest, I don't know. The first time I used **Shared Prefences** (different way that my answer above), it only worked for the class I created it in, so I switched to the way I wrote it in my answer; it always works. Google the difference if you really want to know (Android has documentation).

Comment: Sorry! So in my Activity class I did this: SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("preferenceName",0); and it works. Now, if I understand you right, if I want to access the SharedPreferences named "preferenceName", I create another SharedPreferences object in the second class? The second class is a BroadCastReceiver and doesnt have getSharedPreferences(), how do I solve this?

Comment: I don't know anything about BroadCastReceiver, but if you can't use the `getSharedPreferences("preferenceName",0)` method, I suggest you Google how to use **Shared Preferences** in BroadCastReceiver. I'm not sure if that's a special class you're talking about or something, but that's all I can say on it. Sorry. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098981/sharedpreferences-in-broadcastreceiver-seems-to-not-update

Comment: @user2779837 Check these links out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098981/sharedpreferences-in-broadcastreceiver-seems-to-not-update and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075030/shared-preferences-inside-broadcastreceiver

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **SharedPreferences** to save the settings of your app locally. Refer this link for more details : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `SharedPreferences` as,

To Save:

```
 SharedPreferences settings;
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
 public static final String PREFS_NAME = "app_pref";
 public static final String KEY_p_id = "KEY_test";

    settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(Login_screen.KEY_test, values.get(0));
    editor.commit();
```

To Remove:

```
    editor.remove("KEY_test").commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out SharedPreferences.  It's Android's way of persisting simple values.  Or you could create a full database.

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreferences to save small chunk of app data.
Check the [developer's website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for this.

Also check out this [Tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/) for step by step guide.

Comment: Check out the upload time, people are willing to answer every sec.

Answer (score -3):

You can use local DB like SQlite for for your app.

Comment: Why are suggesting the use of SQLite ? Do you really think its feasible to use DB in this case ?