# Separate Multiple Integers from a String

Tags: java, android, string, substring

I've got a question about making a save function.

I'm trying to have a string be saved as a single file to set specific settings on a game.  So saveFile would read `"002007..."`, having `002` be a player's location, then `007` a player's level, for example.

I understand how to compile the various variables into a single string, but how would I return it to individual variables?

Comment: I see XY problem here.

Comment: Please try out some answers and leave feedback. Accept the one that works best for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a delimiter between the values like this:

```
int location = 02;
int level = 3;
int powerUps = 46;
... and so on

String saveString = location + "#" + level + "#" + powerUps + "#" + ...
```

Then to load the String back into variables:

```
String[] values = saveString.split("#");
location = values[0];
level = values[1];
powerUps = values[2];
... and so on
```

Comment: Okay... thank you.  I think this should work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You better go with `SQLite` or `SharedPreferences` if you really want to save settings for a game on Android.

On the other hand, if you have to stick with saving a `String` on a file, you might want to use a delimiter(ie `\r\n` or `#` or `|` would do it) between numbers. So while parsing back delimiters will help you a lot, but beware when things get complicated a single `String` won't do the thing nicely. Then you might want to use JSON (for simplicity I would prefer `gson`) to encode your settings into one `String` and vice verse.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to check out [Shared Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353758/how-to-save-app-settings/19353944#19353944) and you can read Android's documentation on it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

If you did want to use your single String, file method, I suggest using delimiters. That simply means to put commas, or other types of delimeters in between different integer values. Instead of `"002007"`, save it as `"002,007"`. Example:

```
String s = "002,007"

String[] values = s.split(","); // values[0] is "002" and values[1] is "007"
```

Using the `.split(String)` command will return a String array with each element in the array containing parts of the String that was split up by the parameter, in this case: `,`

If you wanted to separate values per person, something like this could be done:

```
String s = "002,007;003,008";

String[] people = s.split(";"); // people[0] is "002,007", people[1] is "003,004" 

String[][] person = new String[people.length][people[0].split(",").length];

for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++)
{
    person[i] = people[i].split(",");
}
```

Here is what the array would then contain:

> person[0][0] is "002"
> person[0][1] is "007"
>  person[1][0] is "003"
>  person[1][1] is "008"

```
// print it for your own testing
for (String ppl[] : person)
{
    for (String val : ppl)
    {
        System.out.print(val + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```