# Storing string even if the app is closed

Tags: android, string, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to take string from user and use it later when the app is closed..now it works just when the app is in background but i lose the string when i close the app..is there a way to do it like this or i have to use SharedPreference and if i have to use it please explain how because i tried and failed..thanks alot.

this is my code in my MainActivity to the string from the EditText

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private static String reminder;
 private EditText et;
private Intent intent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // initialize variables


    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
            reminder = et.getText().toString();
            if(reminder == null){
                reminder = "TWEAK!";
            }

            editor.putString("TAG",reminder);
            editor.commit();
            // do stuff
}

// get the user's string
public String getRem() {
    reminder = sharedPreferences.getString("TAG", "");
    return reminder;
}
```

the app crashes and gives

> "Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"

at this line

```
reminder = sharedPreferences.getString("TAG", "");
```

this is the class where i call the method

```
public class Notifications extends BroadcastReceiver {
private String rem;

      // set notification
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // object to access MainActivity methods
    MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
    rem = main.getRem();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the whole class(es) as a [mcve], not just these small samples of code? `sharedPreferences` is null because it is not initialized somehow.

Comment: i added my whole MainActivity class..i just was posting snippets related to my question

Comment: Don't add the whole thing, read that link, please. Not all that code you added is related to the SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you called the method of `getRem()`, you can't do that outside the Activity as the SharedPreferences are null.

Like, I assume you made a `new MainActivity()`, then called `getRem()` on that, perhaps?

You need to obtain the SharedPreferences again from an available `Context`, and then you can use `getString("TAG", "")`

**EDIT** Borrowed from [Shared preferences inside broadcastreceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075030/shared-preferences-inside-broadcastreceiver)

```
public class Notifications extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private String rem;

    // set notification
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        setRem(context);
    }

    private void setRem(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        rem = prefs.getString("TAG", "");
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help and your time..that gets it right :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sharedpreferences](/questions/tagged/sharedpreferences)

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("TAG",reminder);
editor.commit();
```

to retrive it:

```
sharedpreferences.getString("TAG","");
```

---

[update]

```
public class Notifications extends BroadcastReceiver { 
private String rem;
 // set notification
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
// object to access MainActivity methods
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES",Context.MODE_PR‌​IVATE);
  rem = sharedPreferences.getString("TAG", ""); 
}
```

more about [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: i tried it and the app still crashes..i added the new code..what am i doing wrong?

Comment: public String getRem() {
reminder = "";
    reminder = sharedPreferences.getString("TAG", "");
    return reminder;
}

Comment: if it's not working please put the whole code for this activity.

Comment: I see that you declare gerRem() method but you did not use it :] 
how the app crash??

Comment: i'm calling it in another class that extends BroadcastReciever..i added it

Comment: public class Notifications extends BroadcastReceiver {
private String rem;

      // set notification
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // object to access MainActivity methods
   SharedPreferences  sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPREFERENCES",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String rem = sharedPreferences.getString("TAG", "");
}

Comment: it's so close the other answer above but when i add MODE_PRIVATE inside onReceive method it turns red..the other answer gets it right..but nonetheless man you are amazing thank you so much for your patience and your time i'm just a beginner and having lot's of hard time so you helped a lot..thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks :D, We rabna m3ak :D